# Programming with ASUS Xtion Pro - it won't read data

Tags: c#, gesture-recognition, openni, asus-xtion

I am using ASUS Xtion Pro and OpenNI to program some gesture recognition.

```
FingertipDetector2D fingertipDetector2D = new FingertipDetector2D(
    new DepthImage(this.depthMetadata.XRes, 
        this.depthMetadata.YRes, 
        this.depthMetadata.DepthMapPtr),
    point3D, 
    (ushort)this.depthGenerator.DeviceMaxDepth);
```

I use the code above to read the data from the device but I getn an exception from ImageAnalyzer.dll.
It says it's a devide by zero exception.

The device is okay since the sample files of OpenNI library work fine.

Does anyone know what the problem might be

Comment: I think you should show more... where is openni initialized? maybe the error is there...

Comment: The initialization is okay, since the application runs okay until here, here is where the exception is thrown

Comment: The initialization can still be missing something, and runs fine, until this missing part is needed... The more you show the easier to find the error... Also, you should show where these constructors are implemented , maybe the error is there